# Obtaining out-of-bag errors with scikit-learn's RandomForestClassifier

Tags: python, machine-learning, random-forest

I'm trying to implement out-of-bag samples so that I won't have to partition my data into a training set and test set for random forest. Looking around, it seems that [RandomForestClassifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html) takes in a boolean parameter `oob_score`, but I'm not sure if this is what will help me. (As far as I know, this only outputs an R^2 estimate?)

In R, using the [randomForest](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/randomForest/randomForest.pdf) package, `predict.RandomForest` automatically does oob if you don't input a data set to predict. Is there an equivalent way in Python?

Comment: What do you want to do with the out-of-bag samples?  As described further down on that page, the fitted model has an `oob_score_` attribute.

Comment: I'd like to obtain classification errors in order to examine the ROC plot.

Comment: What about the `oob_decision_function_` attribute?  I think that gives you oob predicted probabilities for each sample.

Comment: Ah, is that what that attribute is? I wasn't sure what the documentation meant. Thanks!

Comment: I agree it's not totally clear.  I would test it a bit to see if that's what it's doing, but I think that's what it's doing.